# The Google Maps API fails me

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a website and Google Maps is failing me to locate the company.

I have generated a KEY API in the Google console and I have introduced it in WordPress through the "Google maps API Key" plugin.

The case is that the map is seen for 1 second, but then it stops showing and the following error message appears: "An error has occurred, this page has not loaded Google Maps correctly." Discover the technical details of the problem in the javascript console ".

The web in question is: https://arsaiguarderia.com/

[image]
The map is on the home screen at the bottom and on the contact screen.

Comment: What does the console say?

Answer (score 0):

I see this:

js?key=A.....Y&ver=3.4:50 Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: https://arsaiguarderia.com/

Maybe you need to go to your Google Cloud Platform > API project > API > Credentials > API key name. Then set the HTTP referrers restriction to your web site name.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a problem of http referers according to the javascript console, could you make sure your site is not blocked in the google console? Edit your api key and look for application restrictions